# How to stream a response in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, kubernetes

The Kubernetes API exposes an endpoint that allows to watch for resources: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#efficient-detection-of-changes

When sending a request to that endpoint, the connection will remain open and the k8s API will stream data whenever the resources you are watching change.

I want to simply have my rails app run, send the request from a controller and log the stream in the console. I can't figure out how to implement this. By searching I keep stumbling in examples where the rails app itself is streaming data, but that is not what I'm trying to achieve here.

I tested the streaming with `curl` and it works fine:

```bash
curl -s -k -H "Authorization: Bearer XXX" https://localhost:64298/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods\?watch\=1\&resourceVersion\=0
```

I tried several approaches, but I could not make it work. When asking ChatGPT it suggests to use loops with sleep, but I really don't want that, I want the app to *listen* to the changes, not to loop.

One thing I tried is EM:

```rb
# app/workers/k8s_streaming_worker.rb
class K8sStreamingWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform
    k8s_watch_url = "#{KubernetesClientService::CLUSTER_BASE_URI}/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods?watch=1&resourceVersion=0"
    authorization_token = "Bearer #{KubernetesClientService::CLUSTER_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_TOKEN}"

    EM.run do
      puts 'Starting connection...'

      http = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new(k8s_watch_url).get(
        head: { 'Authorization' => authorization_token, 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' },
        keepalive: true,
        tls: { verify_peer: false } 
      )

      http.stream do |chunk|
        puts "Received chunk: #{chunk}"
      end

      http.callback do
        puts 'Connection closed'
        EM.stop
      end

      http.errback do
        puts "Error occurred: #{http.error}"
        EM.stop
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But this does not log anything when there is a change in the cluster.

I believe I will need to create a worker to avoid blocking the main thread of the app.

Can anyone point me to some documentation that shows an example for my use case or give me a hint to move towards the right direction?